# OneToOne JPA does not save null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.1.0.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this object:

```
@Entity
public class TdkDevice extends Device {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public TdkDevice() {
        super();
    }

    public TdkDevice(String deviceKey, String devicePAC) {
        super(deviceKey, devicePAC);
    }



    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User authorizedTeam;

}
```

and in the controller, 
I do this

```
currentDevice.setAuthorizedTeam(null);
deviceService.save(currentDevice);
```

But in the DB there is still the old value

Comment: Can you provide the service implementation?

Comment: Full source code of controller and service would be helpful. BTW - are you sure the changes you made to entity are finally propagated in DB? Using `save` method on repository, as I assume you did, does not guarantee that. Without full source code it's hard to tell what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your hibernate configuration, `save` method on JPA repository may not immediately write your changes to the database, and you will have to flush them once you are done "saving" entities. You can also use `saveAndFlush` method which will force the changes in the object to be written to the database immediately.

[Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-flushing)